# What is the missing part that would fix this outdoor spigot?

Tags: water

[image]

I will probably use the wrong vocabulary. The handle or knob came off the spigot. What is the name of the part I need to buy to fix it? I don’t have the missing part(s). I thought maybe just replace that whole fixture but it’s welded. I tried just getting a new knob but that wasn’t enough stuff to do anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an outdoor [faucet (or spigot) handle kit](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-Universal-Outdoor-Faucet-Handle-10006/202196238)

[image: faucet handle]

> Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources

Comment: Coincidentally to your username, this faucet is also known as a "hose bibb".

Comment: @JPhi1618 My trademark lawyer will call them in the morning.